# How are these two strings different?

Tags: linux, string, hash, diff

Someone please stop me from going insane.

I have two strings that look identical, but are flagged by Linux "diff" as different.  They also have different md5 and sha1 hashes.

Is there a way I can find out HOW they are different?  I've tried converting to ASCII, Unicode, etc. but the results are the same for both strings.  The only thing I can think of is something at the end of the string like a newline, but I haven't been able to figure it out.  Whatever the difference is, it seems to be preserved consistently with copy and paste.

Here are the two strings:

per favore impostami un promemoria per andare in banca

per favore impostami un promemoria per andare in banca

Comment: but copy to windows notepad will not preserve the mysterium?

Comment: At the risk of not being helpful, I just copied these into vim and wrote a Java program to see whether they are equal, and lo and behold, they are indeed the same string. Are you able to copy these strings, from this post, back to your machine and still observe the difference? I'm wondering whether it was stripped when you posted.

Comment: use `xxd` to see the hexdump of characters, then check in which character they are different with `diff` or whatever diff tool

Comment: What is the source of these strings?  The alleged differences weren't preserved when you copied them to the question body.  Maybe you could attach the file that contains them?

Comment: Thanks all.  I did try vimdiff which highlighted the difference and upon doing the Unicode conversion again, I saw that the first string had a regular space but the second had a non-breaking space.  Don't know why that wasn't preserved when I pasted into here.

I did not know about xxd, cat -v, or od.  This will be very useful to me in the future!

Answer (score 2):

several ways:

if the content is in, say, the file "file" :

```
cat -v file
cat file | od
```

if the content is in, say, $string variable :

```
echo "$string" | cat -v
echo "$string" | od
```

even you can add additional "boundaries" to see trailing spaces, etc:

```
cat -v file | sed -e 's/^/___START___/' -e 's/$/___END___/'
```

- od accept many optinos to show content as hex, octal, etc: sometimes you'll see more infos with this or that option.
- cat -v will show special chars as "^x", ^@=\000  ^A=\001  ^B=\002, etc. helps to see for example the trailing "^M".
- the additionnal sed helps to show the tab or space that may be before/after the similar text.